# How to show that the Rust type system supports algebraic data types (ADTs)?

Tags: rust, algebraic-data-types

[Wikipedia's list of programming languages with algebraic data types (ADTs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type#Programming_languages_with_algebraic_data_types) suggests that Rust indeed has ADTs, but I am not sure if my interpretation for why this is true for Rust is correct. As I understand it, to say that one has ADTs one needs to have:

*Values*:

- Zero (or Void) - `!` in Rust) - a type that gets no value.
- One (or Unit) - `()` in Rust) - a type that gets one value: `()` itself.

*Operations*:

- Addition - `enum { A, B }` in Rust - operation that can return the values of `A` or the values of `B`.
- Multiplication - Tuple `(A, B)` in Rust - operation that can return all the combinations of `A` and `B`.

*Rules*:

- `a + b = b + a`: `enum { A, B } =~ enum { B, A }`
- `a * b = b * a`: `(A, B) =~ (B, A)`
- `0 + x = x`: `enum { !, A } =~ enum { A }`
- `0 * x = 0`: `(!, A) =~ !`
- `1 * x = x`: `((), A) =~ A`

Here `A =~ B` means that there is a `fn(A) -> B` and `fn(B) -> A`

Is my description above for why Rust's type system supports ADTs true, or am I missing or misunderstanding something about it?

Comment: `!` is not actually a type in stable Rust, but you can use an empty `enum` for a "zero" type. Though I don't think a zero type is a necessity for a language to have algebraic data types. That said, what exactly is your question?

Comment: My actual question was removed in one of the edits. It is back now.

Comment: Your actual question was not *removed*, it was *moved* — to the title of the post, which is where questions belong on a Question and Answer site. A bundle of nouns like "Algebraic Data Types in Rust" is not a suitable question. You have since modified the title (while keeping it a question, so that's good).

Answer (score 4):

> Is my description above for why Rust's type system supports ADTs true, or am I missing or misunderstanding something about it?

Yes, this is about right. One change I would make is to express `Void` as an `enum`. As interjay said in the comments, `!` is not part of stable Rust ([yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1216-bang-type.md)):

```
enum Void {} // uninhabited
```

The rest follows easily, and I'm not sure that an answer could express it better than you have done yourself in your question.